# SQL query is working directly but not when called from Python (django)

Tags: python, sql, django

```
today_date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%m-%y")
from django.db import connections
with connections['DB'].cursor() as cursor:
    select_query = "select * from <table_name> where <condition_row> like '<PRODUCT_NAME>%' and creation_date like '" +     today_date + "%';"
    cursor.execute(select_query)
```

The select query when executed directly from SQL developer gives output .
But when called from the above script is giving null output .

Comment: Should not you set `today_date` before you execute your SQL request ?

Comment: yes i have added it before the query in my script in here i have missed the order ..

Comment: Please define "null output". Is this a part of a function? Does it `return` anything? In the example you never read the results. On a related note, please do not use string formatting/concatenation to pass values to queries, it is error prone and can open you up for SQL injection. Instead use your driver's placeholders and pass the arguments to `execute()`.